# Import .xlsx file with PHP

Tags: php, excel, xlsx

Here my snippet code

```
require_once 'readernew.php';
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();

$data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
$data->read('InOut.xlsx');

$res = $data->sheets;
var_dump($data);
```

but it give the error like filename is not readable without the password protection

will you please help to access .xlsx file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) to read XLSX.

```
<?php
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('InOut.xlsx');
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
var_dump($sheetData);
```

Comment: Can you please give me the snippet code for use that library.because i m not familiar with that library

Comment: I edited my response with a short example. You can see a documentation and some examples on the repo.

Comment: thank for the snippet coe but it still give the error :  Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Reader_Exception' with message 'Could not open InOut.xlsx for reading! File does not exist.'   require_once 'PHPExcel.php';
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('InOut.xlsx');
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
var_dump($sheetData);exit;

Comment: thanks ,now its working and get readble can you please help me for to get the value from the response i get like this Array
([2] => Array (
            [A] => 194
            [B] => Nilesh Darji
            [C] => 04-01-15
            [D] => 10:04
            [E] => 13:14
            [F] => G2
            [G] => PP
            [H] => 7:52
        ) and want to fetch the data from the array how can i do this ? can you give me the snippet code for that ?